# Air Date Picker not in english

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using the [Air Date Picker](https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker) and my calendar is not picking up the english language. I followed the doc and included the datepicker.en.js and checked and I can see that it is in my page source.

But I put the datepicker in the bootstrap modal and I am wondering if that is causing it to come out in a weird text format.

[image]

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="calendarfilters">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="datepicker-here" data-language='en'></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">Today</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">This Week</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">Yesterday</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">Last Week</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="datepicker-here" data-language='en'></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">This Month</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">This Year</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">Last Month</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="calendar-filter">Last Year</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
;(function ($) { $.fn.datepicker.language['en'] = {
days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
daysShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
daysMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
months: ['January','February','March','April','May','June', 'July','August','September','October','November','December'],
monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
today: 'Today',
clear: 'Clear',
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
timeFormat: 'hh:ii aa',
firstDay: 0
}; })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you show the full page including scripts. Would be great to look it at JSFiddle or codepen. May be different systems can see different language

Comment: I've created a fiddle from your code, it looks just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/0e1oqp0w/ – can you include a screenshot in your question that shows what you mean with “weird text format”

Comment: @PatrickHund I included a pic.

Comment: @sergy I am calling the scripts in my header.                                       <script src='/js/required/datepicker.en.js'></script><script src='/js/required/datepicker.min.js'></script>

Comment: @user3780248 Thanks, that makes it clearer. If you look at my fiddle, you'll see the HTML code you posted works just fine, so I assume it must have something to do with your page's charset or possibly the font you use

Comment: Try to set meta codepage tag as utf: <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
   autoClose: true,
   language: 'en'
})